# create bootable USB (<2GB) with modified linux RT-Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time, gentoo, bootable

The 2GB threshold comes from the fact, that the machine I am working on only supports SD (not SDHC) which are max 2GB big.

So far I have managed to compile the kernel with my adjusted kernel config and applied RT-Patch. But I am stuck trying to get this kernel into my bootable USB. The tutorials I found create Live USBs bigger than 2GB. ([this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Install_Gentoo_on_a_bootable_USB_stick) for example breaks at `tar -xpf ~/Download/portage-latest.tar.xz`) And the minimal Gentoo x86 img does not contain the kernel bzImage or any lib/modules directory:

`2048 2,0K drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 2,0K Sep 29 08:08 gentoo.efimg.mountPoint
  1873 179M -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 179M Sep 29 08:08 image.squashfs
  1920 4,0K drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K Sep 29 08:06 isolinux
  1881    0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Sep 29 08:06 livecd
  1885 7,5K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7,1K Sep 29 08:06 README.txt`

I have gotten so far that I mounted `image.squashfs` and found /mtn/modules but I still can't locate the kernel bzImage.

Can someone point me to a good tutorial or provide one?

Comment: There should be kernel in the `isolinux` directory, check the config isolinux.cfg for exact name